Is Chinese Language SE on the verge of being pulled?
On Area 51 » Culture » Chinese Language, this site have excellent stats except for "questions per day". I thought this would be fine until I saw Area 51 » Business » Startup Business, which has comparable stats with Chinese Language SE (excellent everywhere with the exception of  "questions per day"). Nonetheless that site was pulled after launching for 1176 days despite having more than double avid users than those of Chinese Language SE.
I am a newcomer to Chinese Language SE but I am worrying about the future of this site now. What do you guys think?

By the way: another site's success/failure has no bearing on the fate of a different site. :P
